# Is “call off” used correctly in the sentence below?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I had to call off all of my plans for tomorrow in order to meet you.

And if the sentence doesn’t sound natural, what are the other alternatives I can use instead?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant "I had to call off..." instead of "I had to call of" -- i.e., I assume the sentence is just mis-typed.

The sentence sounds fine to me. It implies the speaker had multiple things planned for the day and had to cancel all of them to meet this person.

Alternatives? "I had to cancel all my plans for the day to meet you."

"I cleared my schedule to meet you."

"There are all kinds of things I'm not doing so that I can meet you."

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! And yes I meant “call off”,but for some reason I can’t edit my question to correct it..